# Gensim Word2Vec - can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, gensim, word2vec

I have a panda series around 300k lines (one text per line). I wanted to extract the output array for each line of a trained W2V on a testing data set using the following code:

```
import gensim

w2v = gensim.models.Word2Vec(list(X_train), hs=1, negative=0)
l = [w2v.score(e) for e in list(X_test)]
```

Here is the error I received (when it does not kill my ipython session)

```
error: can't start new thread
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which line triggers this error? Is there any other information shown, like a more detailed error stack? If there is a problem creating threads, it is probably something specific to your system, totally unrelated to gensim/word2vec.

Comment: The error is made in the last line and does not provide any further explanation? I first thought each time the score method was called it was creating a new thread and made the system crash at some point.

Comment: Any limit on thread creation would be something about your system – that error message isn't generated by gensim code. But also note that `score()` already expects a list of sentences, so you don't have to call it many times in a list-comprehension-loop. Since calling it once will create far fewer threads than calling it `len(X_test)` times, maybe that will help avoid the error.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes and it works perfectly now!